# $http.jsonp retrieves data correctly but does not pass it to .success function

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, pagination, instagram

Working with the Instagram API trying to do pagination correctly.

I have the following function, getMoreUsers, which, when fired, should push the next set of users into my $scope.followers variable, and then set the pagination variable to the new pagination URL provided in the returned JSON.

```
$scope.getMoreUsers = function() {
  console.log("i have been clicked");
  console.log('pagination: ' + pagination);
  $http.jsonp(pagination).success(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    debugger;
    $scope.followers.push(result.data);
    pagination = result.pagination.next_url;
    console.log("followers" + $scope.followers);
  })
  .error(function(result) {
    console.log('uh-oh', result);
  });

};
```

When I click on the link with the corresponding ng-click attribute, the "i have been clicked" and pagination logs are correctly sent to the console. The next log in the console is "uh-oh", undefined, suggesting that there was an error in the jsonp call. However, in Chrome's network tab, I see a GET request to the url specified by the pagination variable, with a 200 status.

So, for some reason, the jsonp call is reaching and retrieving the right information, but the error function is being called instead of the success function. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you appending`?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the end of your url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK to the end of your url.